# Objective C: Try catch not working -- how to set it up?

Tags: objective-c, exception, xcode6, try-catch, app-id

```
@try{
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];
}
@catch(NSException* e)
{
     NSLog(@"FBAppCall Error %@", e);
}
@finally{

}
```

It's not getting into the catch phase. so it always throws out the exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBAppBridge: AppID not found; Add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'

What can I do so that the try catch thing will work?
I am using release mode now and `Xcode` 6.

Comment: How do you know that the exception is occurring in the code in the `@try` block? Show the stack trace.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Facebook SDK, but I would check if it is a C++ exception that it throws.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the error message? It points you to the problem!

> reason: 'FBAppBridge: AppID not found; Add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'

If you are going to use the `facebook SDK` you always need the AppId, created in the [developer center.](https://developers.facebook.com/)